# Using variables in javascript and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flask

I would like to use a variable which I passed to the html template via flask in a javascript code. Here is an example: I have a list which I passed to the html template and I run a for loop over that list

```
<body>
   {% for group in groups %}
      <input class="group_sel" type="checkbox" id="{{ group[0] }}" name="groupstoselect[]" value="{{ group[0] }}">{{ group[0] }}
      </input><br>
   {% endfor %} 
</body>
```

here I have a list (groups) and loop over that list. My question is if I want to do that loop in a jquery statement, how would that work?

thanks

carl

Answer (score 0):

Server side template generates list of checkboxes with the same class `.group_sel`. Now on the client you can select this collection and loop over it with this code:

```
$('.group_sel').each(function() {
    console.log( this.value );
});
```

Also make sure your HTML is valid, remove `</input>`, it should be:

```
{% for group in groups %}
    <input class="group_sel" type="checkbox" id="{{ group[0] }}" name="groupstoselect[]" value="{{ group[0] }}"> {{ group[0] }}
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer dfsq... my question was more whether there is any way to directly access the groups list in a javascript statement. Lets say I don't want to have the for loop in the html code but want to generate that html code using javascript?

Comment: Then you need to inject JSON structure into your script, and create those items with script. Easy if you add `groups` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Theres no big change if you just want to move the Jinja to a javascript that works in the same way as defining it in the html.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = {{ groups }}
    d.forEach(function(entry) {
       console.log(entry);
    });
```

You might have to add the `|safe` filter to groups. `{{ groups|safe }}`

The safe filter explicitly marks a string as "safe", i.e., it should not be automatically-escaped if auto-escaping is enabled. See http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping